# How to trigger k8s Job from different application?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, jobs

I will briefly describe my application workflow: I have one application (cronjob), this application read my database and I want to, based on the output from database, run a few jobs in Kubernetes. Sometimes 1 job, sometimes 10 jobs, it depends. Additionally, I would like to pass some env's to this job.

How Can I do that in the most proper way? Probably I should use K8s API but are there any other options?

Comment: @MikolajS. Unfortunately I think it will not work in my case, because I am using Autopilot Kubernetes Engine and I dont want to have pods running all the time (I just need Kubernetes jobs to do the workfload). Do you  have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Tekton?

Their EventListener would allow you to trigger jobs through some HTTP endpoint, and may allow you to set environment variables based on your payload.

See:

- https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/docs/pipelines.md
- https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/docs/tasks.md
- https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/blob/main/docs/eventlisteners.md